# Echo special characters from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I am having Mysql database with column type of `varchar(8192) latin2_croatian_ci`. There i insert text like this: `Čćžvasfamižsafaš` (this is random text with special characters). When i preview data in mysql it does have that speical character (it wasn't replaced with `?` or something else).

I have `php` page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();
    include("somePhpFile");

    $cid = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET["id"]);

    $sql = "SELECT BODY FROM ... WHERE CLANAKID = '$cid'";
    if($result = $mysqli->query($sql))
    {
        $clanak = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $body = $clanak["BODY"];
    }
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/Clanak.css?id=4" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/DefaultBody.css" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jQuery/Header.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("someHeaderphp");?>
    <div id="BodyDiv">
        <?php echo($body); ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And when i echo it inside my page all special characters get replaced with `?` and other characters. What could i do?

Here is my `Show create table`:

```
CREATE TABLE `CLANAK` (
 `CLANAKID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `NASLOV` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `BODY` varchar(8192) CHARACTER SET latin2 COLLATE latin2_croatian_ci NOT NULL,
 `THUMBNAIL` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
 `AKTIVAN` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`CLANAKID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php and also check charset of the http `Content-Type`

Comment: @Deadooshka Thank you. Adding simple `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's do some debugging.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and

Let's see `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to dump what got into the table.  For `Čćžvasfamižsafaš`, the HEX will be

```
3F3F3F76617366616D693F736166613F (???vasfami?safa?) - the text was messed up when storing.
C8E6BE76617366616D69BE73616661B9 - if it stored correctly into a latin2 column
C48CC487C5BE76617366616D69C5BE73616661C5A1 - correctly stored into utf8 (or utf8mb4)
```

[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)